# adding input box dynamically when filling the other input box

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have a form like this

```
<FORM method="post">
<TABLE>
<TR>
    <TD>Username</TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" value="" name="username" title="Enter Username"/><TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Age</TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" value="" name="username" title="Enter Age"/><TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>City</TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" value="" name="username" title="Enter City"/><TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Comment</TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" value="" name="username" title="Enter Comment"/><TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>
```

what i want is when user after filling the comment box ,when they press enter then dynamically another input box has to display with comment label by using javascript.

can anyone help me to write the code...

Comment: Do you want it only after they press the "return" key or after they enter in anything?

Comment: after they enter the comment and when they press enter key,in that time another input box has to come with comment label dynamically

Comment: Can you use jQuery or does it have to be straight javascript?

Comment: Have you tried `onkeydown="dothis();"` and `function dothis() {$('tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="mynewinput"/></td></tr>');}`

Comment: @Romo - please avoid extended code snippets in comments. Please post an answer if you feel you have one. Also, DOM level zero events (inline events) should be avoided in JavaScript.

Comment: @kanya - what have you looked into/tried?

Comment: i tried like this <TR>
    <TD>Comment</TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" value="" name="username" title="Enter Comment" onkeydown="dothis();"/><TD>
</TR>

Comment: and script is <script>
function dothis()
 {$('tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="mynewinput"/></td></tr>');}
</script>

Comment: and one more thing after filling this dynamically input box ,another input box has to display dynamically and the process is going on..

Comment: is it possible by using JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your all the input names in your form are the same (name="username"), you have to give each input a unique name.

so change comment input to

```
<TR id="comment">
    <TD>Comment</TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" value="" name="comment[]" title="Enter Comment"/><TD>
</TR>
```

note that i added id to the TR so it'll be easier to latch on to it using jquery and i also changed the input name to be `comment[]` since if you add a new comment to the dom you'll have a comment array.

if the new comment should have a new name like : 'comment2', you can change it to be just 'comment'

Now, using Jquery do the following:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    //catch enter event
    if(e.which == 13) {
         var $comment = $('#comments);
        //check that the user entered something in the comment input
        if($comment.find('input').val().length > 0)
        {
            //create new comment element and attach it to DOM
            var $newComment = $comment.clone().removeAttr('id');
            $('form table').append($newComment);
        }
    }
});
```

let me know if that helped or if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend:

```
<FORM method="post">
    <TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TD>Username</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="" name="username" title="Enter Username"/><TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Age</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="" name="age" title="Enter Age"/><TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>City</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="" name="city" title="Enter City"/><TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Comment</TD>
        <TD><INPUT class="comment" type="text" value="" name="comment[]" title="Enter Comment"/><TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
</FORM>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.comment').live('keydown', function(e){
            $field = $(this);
            // capture enter key being pressed
            if (e.which == 13)
            {
                $html = $(this).parents('tr').clone();
                $html.find('input').val('');
                $html.appendTo($field.parents('table'));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```